# Flexiforce to Uno to Keyboard. Working but not as inteded

Tags: java, macos, keyboard, arduino, arduino-uno

I have a Flexiforce 25 pound pressure sensors connected to my Arduino Uno which connects to my laptop. My requirement is to be able to play video games using taps on pressure sensors. I am successfully sending signals to my Laptop and I am using Java on my Mac to send keystrokes (Key Down and Key Up) signals to move in the game. However I am facing issues with long key down and key up. How do I detect that and make sure that my program runs smooth?

Uno code:

```
void setup() {}

void loop() {
int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
int sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);
int sensorValue3 = analogRead(A2);
int sensorValue4 = analogRead(A3);
int sensorValue5 = analogRead(A4);
int sensorValue6 = digitalRead(2);

// Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
float voltage2 = sensorValue2 * (5.0 / 1023.0);
float voltage3 = sensorValue3 * (5.0 / 1023.0);
float voltage4 = sensorValue4 * (5.0 / 1023.0);
float voltage5 = sensorValue5 * (5.0 / 1023.0);
float voltage6 = sensorValue6 * (5.0 / 1023.0);

if(voltage > 1){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("A0"); Serial.end();
}
if(voltage2 > 1){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("A1"); Serial.end();
}
if(voltage3 > 1){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("A2"); Serial.end();
}
if(voltage4 > 1){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("A3"); Serial.end();
}
if(voltage5 > 1){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("A4"); Serial.end();
}
if(voltage6 > 0){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("D2"); Serial.end();
}
// Wait 100 milliseconds
delay(100);
}
```

In java I'm using `java.wt.Robot` and `gnu.io.SerialPort` to press key and read from serial port. On a serialEvent I will override the listener function to perform my operation which is press Keys on my machine.

Java Code:

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            String inputLine = null;
            if (input.ready()) {
                inputLine = input.readLine();
                if (inputLine.contains("A0")) {

                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                    }
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                    System.out.println("UP");

                } else if (inputLine.contains("A1")) {

                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                    }
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                    System.out.println("DOWN");

                } else if (inputLine.contains("A2")) {

                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                    }
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                    System.out.println("LEFT");

                } else if (inputLine.contains("A3")) {

                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
                    }
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
                    System.out.println("RIGHT");

                } else if (inputLine.contains("A4")) {

                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                    }
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                    System.out.println("S");

                } else if (inputLine.contains("D2")) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                    System.out.println("D");

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This performs Up, Down, Left, Right, "S" and "D" operation for SuperMario 3 GBA game. This works but not as smooth as intended. Is there anything that I can use to directly bind to my keyboard to get a smoother key operations.

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth"? Anyway you can connect directly to the usb port and make the arduino show itself as a HID peripheral (in this case, a keyboard). You can then send keystrokes directly from the board instead of using a program/service on the pc. You can use a USB-enabled arduino board (e.g. leonardo) or write your own program (using, for instance, the V-USB library)

Comment: By Smooth I mean right now there is a delay in continuous action. Let's say I hold the sensor for a while. Arduino sends multiple keystrokes and that gets executed. Even if I'm not pressing it will take a while to stop the sent key strokes.

Comment: I have downloaded the V-USB library but I am not able to send Keystrokes directly from Arduino. Is there a way to debug through this? Thanks. I started working on Arduino Uno and then realised that I should've ordered Leonardo instead. This is for a final project and I think it will be a bit late for me to swap with Leonardo and start working on that.

Comment: Did you follow [this article](http://www.practicalarduino.com/projects/virtual-usb-keyboard)? V-USB is a library for ATmel processors, so the only time I used it was without the arduino framework, but I used avr-gcc to compile a C++ program

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use an Arduino Leonardo (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLeonardo) or Arduino Micro (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMicro) instead of an UNO. This would allow you to use the built-in Keyboard library (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard) to do your keypresses, eliminating the need to convert the serial data to keypresses.

Another advantage of using the Leonardo or Micro is giving you the option to have this device appear as a game controller/joystick using the Arduino Joystick library (you can read about this library at http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-LeonardoMicro-as-Game-ControllerJoystick/ or http://mheironimus.blogspot.com/2015/11/arduino-joystick-library.html).